# Unknown Intent Flag on Launcher Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an `Activity` with `launchmode = "singleInstance"` and it is the launcher `Activity` of the app. Now I am trying to detect which `Flag` my `Activity` was/will be launched with, but I can not find the flag id with the `Intent` `Flag`s on the [documented page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html); this is the flag

```
String version of the Flag id is 270532608
```

and String version of the Intent is

```
04-25 20:18:57.061: V/logtag(1665): Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
        cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=<filtered> }
```

when the application first starts, the system calls my `Activity` with this `Flag` =  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or string version = `268435456` (which it should)  but when I quit the app, and start it once more from the launcher I get this flag `0x10200000` instead of the previous flag

> so my question is can anyone tell me what Flag this is?
>
> and why my activity is being called with it?
>
> and are there any other instances from the launcher that my activity might be triggered with a different flag aside from the unknown one & 0x10200000?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a combination of the flags:

```
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 0x10000000;
```

and

```
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED = 0x00200000;
```

0x10000000 is the hexadecimal notation for 268435456.
0x00200000 is the hexadecimal notation for 2097152.
If you add these numbers, you get:
0x10200000, which is the hexadecimal notation for 270532608.

So the first time you start your app, you just get `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, but the second time you will also get `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`. This is just a bitwise OR operation.
To check if your desired flag is active, you can do a bitwise AND like this:

```
boolean hasNewTaskFlag = (flg & FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) != 0;
```

Comment: Omg!! Sir? if i may ask, do you know this by experience or there is some source, i am not doubting you, i just need to be informed so as i can be able to detect combinations as you pointed out? btw you have my upvote

Comment: All of the flags cam be seen in the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: You just need to do bitwise operations to see which flags are active.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this `flag` `0x10200000` value is in `Hexadecimal` not in `Decimal` that's why you might not find any useful info if you tried to Google it.

That's why you have to [convert](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) it first to Decimal. Then you will see that the real `flag` value is `270532608` which means **start a new task over the previous one**

> why my activity is being called with it?

Because you probably resuming the instance that was in the background (Recent app list). Not starting a new instance

*If you want to read more about this intent flag click [here](https://www.google.ae/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20flag%20270532608)*

reference: [Start new activity in window manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21457006/1364896)

Comment: so if i had `excludefromrececents = true;` there will be chance that i would not get this flag? i am trying to catch scenarios Sir, and it's because of the `singleinstance` right? what if i had `singletask`? but i think even though i did not pay attention to it, that my activity with its task did finish. and quick catch i was not googling for the hexadecimal number (: just a word out,

Comment: Using `android:noHistory = "true"` will let you get that flag again if you back press with your launcher activity and relaunch again.

Comment: yes but on this activity i spark startActivityforResult & with that i would not get my return intent, so i excluded it from my options @TheLittleNaruto but thanks Sir,

Comment: Okay , so now you say that, that makes sense. There can be other way too, like you can call `finish()` as soon as your launcher activity has done the job.And relaunching the launcher activity thereafter will reproduce the same flag. :-)

Comment: @Elltz you have to give them a try or you can simple handle this `Intent` value and do a specific action for it