# How to identify that a user came from laucher or from shortcut of my Android App?

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I am developing an android app where i am creating a shortcut from `HomeActivity` and from that shortcut i move back to `HomeActivity`.

My problem is i want to send some url in shortcut and want to get back that url when user come from shortcut to `HomeAtivity`.

Here's code :

HomeActivity

```
private void addShortcut() {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("shortcutKey", "www.myapi.com/fromshortcut");
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, AppConstants.shortcutTitle);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AppConstants.shortcutDone, 40).show();
```

Shortcut is created successfully.
Now i click on Shortcut and come back to `HomeActivity` and getting `Intent` but with null pointer exception...

```
String  shortcutUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("shortcutKey");

    if(shortcutUrl.equals("")){

        setupWebView("http://stackoverflow.com");

    }
    else{

        Log.e("shortcut was created", "url from shortcut");
        setupWebView(shortcutUrl);

    }
```

So what should i do to get that data back.Thanks in advance and ready to vote up for right answer.

Comment: You should't use the ApplicationContext so much -> http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: When answers to your question start with "if I understood correctly", you know you're asking a bad question....

Comment: i am not using Application context but getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you you launch your app with a click on the home screen android opens your app with a default simple `Intent` like this in `String` format

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
    cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] - } // the "-" represent flags
```

this `Intent` does not have a `Bundle` with `Key` `shortcutKey` that is why you having a `NPE`

*Your title question and explanation is making me drift left & right*

Try these

1: get the `Activity`'s Intent and put your url to it via `putExtras()` and reCreate() your `Activity`.

```
getIntent().putExtra("key", "my url");
this.startActivity(getIntent());
this.finish(); // or instead of calling the last two do Activity.recreate()
```

the catch here is in your `onCreate()` you check for `Intent.hasExtras();` if true then you have your url which means it has been navigated to it, if not  you dont have your url,which means you in by the shortcut so you do the logic (that is if you do not have `singleInstance` on your `HomeActivity`)

2: or if you have `singleInstance` set on your `Activity` then you can check using `Flag`s check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875772/unknown-intent-flag-on-launcher-activity) especially the question - will guide you on how to check using `Flag`s.

Hope all of that was Lucid and helpful

Comment: hey i uesd Intent.hasExtra(key); and it works thanks @Elltz atleast you gave me hint here...

Comment: so you have solved it? if d answer is yes by my answer you can accept & upvote sir@Rohit Goswami

Answer (score 0):

If i got you correctly, you want url as data back to your home `Activity` from your shortcut if yes then Start your `Activity` for result with method `startActivityForResult()`.

Below callback url will give you result back as `Intent`.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)          {

}
```

Comment: No no i am not starting activity from startActivity i am using broadcast here man....